# How to add dynamic created css using drupal_add_css

Tags: 7, theming, javascript

I am trying to add a file which is located in sites/default/files/color/theme-768/color.css using `drupal_add_css()`.

I have tried `drupal_add_css($filepath)`, but it doesn't work. I tried putting it in template.php and `hook_init()`, but still it isn't included in the style tags of head section or anywhere.

How I do include a CSS file like this using `drupal_add_css()`?

Comment: This is the same question you already asked. If you have more information to add to a question, please edit it. Asking the same question more than once causes the new questions to be closed as duplicates.

Comment: @Ram I'm also struggling with the same issue for a week, I dynamically created css using color module and couldnt figure out how to include it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno:  have deleted that question now, since its not been properly constructed or properly asked. can any one help with this.Now its not duplicate i think.

Comment: Since it didn't have any answer, you could have edited the old question.

Comment: I thought i kind of twisted that question, so tat only.Any suggestions regarding this one :)

Comment: Not sure why you insist on that location, but if you're trying to save custom color settings by overriding this file, then you're not on the right track. Maybe this article will help you understand how the color module works - [Becomig friends with the Drupal color module](http://www.wunderkraut.com/tags/color-module)

Comment: Its not that insist on that path, actually that file will automatically get substituted with themes/color.css file. But for me its not happening.So i am trying to add that file from tat place dynamically by picking the location(sites/default/files/color/theme-54454/color.css) and part of the folder name.Hope you understood what i am trying to do? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a alternate way to include css file which is in some other location other than modules and themes.In my case including a dynamically generated file.
Even though i can't find a way through drupal_add_css(),this helped me in adding css.

This is the way i included dynamically generated css file which is located at `sites/default/files/color/theme-768/color.css`

In the theme folder in the html.tpl.php  after `<?php print $styles;?>` include this

```
<?php    
       print '<style>';
       print '@import url("' . $filepath . '")';
       print '</style>';
?>
```

This includes the css file.